# How to get post meta value and post in one query?

Tags: wp-query

When query a post, I need not only the post but also the post_meta. But seems the post query and meta query can not be done together.

With WP_Query, I first get the posts, then, I need to do `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'key',true)`

Is this the way WP works? Or, is there a way to query both in one hit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### When you do a query WordPress already gets the post_meta.

Even though you are calling `get_post_meta()` It is not performing another query.  It is retrieving the value from the post meta cache.

Now if you don't need the post meta you can set a flag that will eliminate the additional MySql query.  To do this you set `'update_post_meta_cache' => false` in your args.

Comment: So, how to get the meta value when get the query results?

Comment: The meta_value is retrieved when you get the query_results.  You have to call get_post_meta() just like you have to call the_content()

Comment: Is post meta been cached when I call `get_post`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) to return an array of all meta values so that you don't have to use the meta_key for each.

I was not aware that WP cached the meta data, thanks Chris_O.