# Retrieve featured image (thumbnail) url from multiple posts with one query

Tags: wp-query, database, post-thumbnails

I have a list of post ids and need to get all the standard data plus the thumbnail of the posts.
As there will be several hundred posts i need an efficient way to retrieve the data, just looping over all the ids and using has_thummbnail... and all the other versions of the same 'one by one' approach will just not work fast enough.

**So the question is:**

how can i retrieve multiple post with their thumbnail url without making one query for each id

**UPDATE:**

As cybmeta pointed out with the linked posts, [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) does not create an additional DB Query and with that function it is possible to retrieve a post's custom fields.

**BUT** that still doesn't give me the URL of the thumbnail, just the thumbnail's ID. When retrieving the URL by one of the possible methods ([wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), [wp_get_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata), ...) i create an additional DB Query for each thumbnail as those functions do not take multiple IDs!

**More specific question:**

How can i retrieve the url of multiple thumbnails via their id in one query

Comment: See [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66748/how-to-get-post-meta-value-and-post-in-one-query) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta). They are mostly the same issue of your question with interesting and helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks, i did search for a couple of hours but did not find those two :) Did not know that the meta data is retrieved by WP_Query but just not added to the result. Will do some performance tests on that one.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, you were right about the get_post_meta not needing an additional DB Query, but with that i can only retrieve the ID of the thumbnail. To get its URL i have to use one of the various helper functions which all create another DB query...

Comment: I've edited the title of your question, I think now it describes the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

As mentioned in my update above, to retrieve the ID of a thumbnail the [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function can be used without any additional DB overhead.
The 'normal' way to get the url to a thumbnail id is with [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) or similar functions, but those do not accept an array of IDs.

What i noticed using *wp_get_attachment_image_src* was that it created even TWO querys per call (ergo per thumbnail), one to get the post data and then another one for the actual url.

**SOLUTION**

The only solution i found to retrieve more than one url at the same time was to directly query the DB postmeta table via [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

There is a *postmeta* entry for the relation post->thumbnail with the *meta_key* *_thumbnail_id* and the thumbnails id as the *meta_value* and then two more entries per thumbnail with the *meta_tags* *_wp_attachment_metadata* and *_wp_attached_file* and the thumbnail's id as the *post_id*.

So the interesting part of the postmeta table looks like this:

```
meta_id  post_id    meta_key                meta_value
328      136       _wp_attached_file        2015/01/Dog-w-Glasses.jpg
329      136       _wp_attachment_metadata  a:5{s:5:"width";i:...
...
335      138       _thumbnail_id            136
```

with 138 being the post's id and the *meta_id* being irrelevant for this example.

As the *_thumbnail_id* was linked to the *post_id* it could be retrieved via the get_post_meta, but as the actual url was stored under the thumbnails id it had to be retrieved seperately.

So what i did was retrieving all the thumbnail ids for each post via *get_post_meta* and then creating a query to the postmeta table of the WP Database:

```
$thumb_ids = '( 23, 89, 24, 69 )'; // just an example
global $wpdb;
$qstr =
    "SELECT post_id, meta_value
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE post_id IN " . $thumb_ids. ' AND meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $qstr, ARRAY_N );
```

this will return the results in the form of a non-associative array, see the wpdb page for more info on the parameters of that function.

This way only one extra DB call is being used to retrieve all the urls for all the posts.

**p.s.:** I used [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) to analyse the DB queries.

Answer (score -1):

More clear code to achieve post thumbnail full URL. After getting post thumbnail you just has to use word-press built in method **wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );** to achieve full URL.

global $wpdb;

```
            $to = "2017/10/25";
            $from = "2017/10/27";
            $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $tablename 
            /*JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
            JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
            JOIN $wpdb->terms t ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id)*/
            Where post_type =%s AND  post_date BETWEEN %s AND %s  ",'post',$to, $from);
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
            //print_r($results);
            foreach ( $results as $post )
            {

                $id = $post['ID'];
                //echo  $post['parent'].'<br/>';
                echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );


            }
```

Comment: Again, it is not clear what the answer is here. Why using the date range?

Comment: Sorry about it i was working on another project so the code belong to it. you just has to query to retrieve posts from database and use foreach in foreach you'll get list of ids as you have list of thumbnail. Here no need to have list of thumbnail ids here you can direct print post thumbnails by just using wordpress method wp_get_attachment_url .

Comment: Did you verify that this does not generate additional DB Queries? This is not only about how to get the information, but also how to get it as efficiently as possible

Comment: yes no additional staff i used it in my project it is working like a charm bro